# python Socket.io client default port number

Tags: python, node.js, heroku, socket.io

I'm using heroku for trying some example with node.js and Socket.io. So I have a server on heroku which using socket.io.

I want to connect and communicate my server to a python client script via Socket-io-client library. But i can't find the port number. I have to use a port number for connect to heroku server.

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace
with SocketIO('https://heroku......', 8000, LoggingNamespace) as socketIO:
    socketIO.emit('foo', 'bar')
    socketIO.wait(seconds=1)
```

8000, 8080, 80, 8888, 443 are not works. How can i connect to server? The socket.io libraries which uses another programming language are letting connect to server without port number. But in python i must pass. Is there any solution?

Comment: maybe this for the port: `int(os.environ.get('PORT', 3000))` also you have to import the `os` module

Comment: just waiting. Nothing happened in python side console.I think it is trying to connect but it can't

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to `https://...`, socket IO is hosted always in `ws://...` unless you had changed it